# Sum of many outer products in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I have two matrices `A` and `B` both with shape `(N,M)`. I would like to perform the following operation: `C = np.sum(A[:,None,:]*B[:,:,None],axis=(1,2))`, which corresponds to performing the sum of the outer product of each row of `A` with each row of `B`. `C` would then have a shape of `(N,)`.

The problem is that I get a `MemoryError` when using this form because `N=12000` and `M=4000`.

Is there a way to perform this operation without having to first build the (huge) intermediary array to be summed ?

I suspect a solution with `np.einsum` would do the trick, but I'm not familiar with it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if `np.einsum` solves the memory issue, but below is equivalent of your calculation using it:

```
C = np.einsum('ij,ik->i',A,B)
```

Comment: Thanks ! `np.einsum` is definitely faster and uses less memory, I'll check if it solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers: this operation is mathematically equivalent to multiplying the sum of each row of `A` with the sum of each row of `B`. In other words, the fastest solution is `C = np.sum(A,axis=-1) * np.sum(B,axis=-1)`.

This is much faster than `np.einsum` and any other way of computing it.